# search content of pages and list in wp-admin

Tags: posts, plugin-development, search

I am developing a plugin, and I want to display a page that lists every page on the site that is using a specific shortcode defined by my plugin.

I assume that I need to manually search wp_posts, but I am curious if there is a built in function or a better way to do this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a search term in a `WP_Query` or `get_posts()` call:

```
$pages = get_posts(
    array (
        's'         => '[shortcodename',
        'post_type' => array ( 'page', 'post' )
    )
);
```

Comment: Can this handle multiple search terms? '[shortcode' and a parameter with the shortcode. (I'd just do '[shortcode id=#', but there could be multiple parameters in any order).

Comment: Yes, it should. Not sure what happens when only the parameters are found on page, but not the shortcode. Try it.

Comment: I ran into the problem that id="1", id='1', and id=1 are all possible parameters, but are selective in search.  Do you have any other ideas?  Otherwise, this is working nicely, but I need some sort of this, this, or this for the id.

Comment: As a work around, I'm going to just search for the shortcode, and search the array after that.  Thank you!